# Postman correctly url encodes ø but RestTemplate will not

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a url, that has ø in it. For example this:

```
https://server/ø
```

When I make the GET call in postman, the url is converted correctly into

```
https://server/%C3%B8
```

But when I use Java code like this:

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(new URI(url));
String out = restTemplate.getForObject(builder.toUriString(), String.class);
```

It correctly turns the url into

```
https://server/%25C3%25B8
```